# Ubuntu doesn't work with my laptop

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I have been trying to use Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Pavilion laptop with a AMD Turion64 x2 processor. I've tried using "Try Ubuntu" with both the 32 and 64 bit editions. (run from separate DVD disks burned from ISO) I have tried an actual install of 14.04.  I also tried to run the installed 64 bit version (updated to 14.1) from a USB memory stick.

In all 4 cases the run works up until I get to the desktop. (At least I can mouse select "Try Ubuntu" but that's it). No mouse, no touchpad, no keyboard use, no internet recognition. I tried the USB mouse in all three plugs.

Everything works fine in Vista. Is this a drivers problem?

I have run my desktop from the USB stick.  Works fine.

Comment: I'm a little confused - you say in all 4 cases it does not get to the desktop, and in the last sentence that you can run the desktop from the USB - what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a similar issue to me.
I did a clean install of ubuntu 14.04 on my hp nx6325 with a turion 64x2 cpu.
at the moment mine works but doesnt shutdown probably because the Modem was unrecognised and therefore causes issues.
i was advised on here to do the Ctrl-Alt-F6 to switch screens to see the login/text screen. This allows you to see the error messages displayed.
most likely a faulty driver is preventing it from continuing (finishing its login)

so the differences between our pcs might be

1) the modem(if any)
2) blutooth(if any)
3) the wireless card make/model
4) the Lan make/model.

you could try disabling the wireless card/blutooth in the bios then do a complete re-install, then maybe you will be in the same state as me.